# Does discretionary effort make sense in a Scrum team?

Tags: career-development

I am a full stack software developer and have managed to cut my workload down to about 15 hours of actual work a week.

Firstly, I discovered a long forgotten document describing the APIs and architecture of of our main system (from the time when people kept track of any of that). It is not known by others (including the team lead) that the document exists. Currently, everyone is rooting around like pigs hunting for truffles searching for APIs which do their tasks. They don't know about it due to turnover and I found it searching old files.

Second, bought a Udemy course in Selenium testing for the usually manual QA who sits beside me and taught her to use the inspector tools. Her bug reports to me now point out exactly where in the process a bug was caused rather than just the presence of the bug. She can also use inspector tools to know which API call failed. She won't do this for other developers as they yell at her for "spamming the bug ticket with crap. " That often makes bug fixes take 5 minutes.

Third, I talk to the business analyst about what is to be done next. That lets me volunteer for items which look lengthy but can actually be done more quickly. I am fine with difficult, but I try to wiggle out of any of the repetitive stuff is just poking stuff until it works. Like CSS or unit testing. I will happily take on a hard bug.

Now, Scrum is team thing in that the team is at fault for failure and the team gets to take credit for all success. This is essentially communism and brings with it the same strategic dilemma.

In Scrum teams, would improvements come with any individual recognition or am I better off just keeping these things hidden and putting my remaining 15 hours a week elsewhere?

I also have to consider that I did not write the document (I copy and paste it and add to it with the new APIs so it seems like my work), so just revealing it wouldn't get me a lot of credit.

In practice, how does the incentive structure work in Scrum? As it seems like the most rational thing to do is to regress to just above the mean and direct the time and energy to outside work career building.

I am kind of concerned for my resume in a Scrum environment as everyone being responsible for everything seems like a good way to seemingly have achieved nothing in your job.

Comment: There recently was a smilar post: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154109/how-can-people-who-don-t-really-like-team-dynamics-effectively-build-careers-wit

Comment: If I were your co-worker I wouldn't really care about you slacking off if you were already and no one was noticing but if I found out that you found the readme for the api endpoints and just didn't say anything while everyone was struggling with it I wouldn't trust you to do anything useful.  Also, Scrum == communism is wrong. No one is going to deny your individual contributions, it's just a team organization pattern. You don't share a paycheck, do you?

Answer (score 14):

Pre-note:
Scrum or no scrum (it really doesn't need scrum to have team work, any good team will have a common sense of success and failure): If I were the team lead and I'd find out you deliberately a) made it look like you are busy when you are not, b) withheld vital helpful information from the team when you knew it was needed and c) unilaterally arranged to pick the "sweet tasks" for yourself leaving all the "boring ones" to your colleagues,  there's a good chance I'd try to get rid of you as all of that is potentially quite poisonous behaviour regarding team spirit*.

That being said: **Sharing success and failure as a team is typically "just" meant as a basic self-understanding within your daily business**. When you write up your CV or discuss a promotion, **you naturally can argue with your personal contributions/achievements** within the team. It's not that you do every task together (unless perhaps you are a team of 2 and always use pair programming... and then still all your shared success you can partially claim anyway).

*This assumes the team is somewhat functional. If it is as a whole dysfunctional/toxic, that would need to be handled in general.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr **Share your discoveries and insights** with your team if you possibly can.

You're doing a great job with  working smart and helping your QA co-worker work smart. Those kinds of things show real excellence. Don't lose sight of that excellence.

Your company's management has, for better or worse, chosen the "scrum" methodology to organize teamwork for people in your profession.  Your  front-office people have decided that teams working together, and sharing in success, is what they want for their company.

Is there a **trust problem** in your team? Is the structure of your team stifling your creativity? Have your co-workers made it clear that showing initiative is bad for your team -- makes them look bad, or some such foolishness? Are you afraid that helping your team work smart will just make the front office want more and  more work from you and the rest of the team?

If there is such a team trust problem, you have two choices:  1) get another job, or 2) work on resolving the trust problem.  In my opinion, and with respect, it's **not an option to withhold** your knowledge from the team.

If you shared your work -- your discovery of the documentation, your effort training your QA colleague, your insights about future work --  you'd go a long way to helping **fix the trust problem** in your team. Generosity and openness are powerful ways to create more generosity and openness.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here, some good and some not so good. All of these are independent of the fact that you are using Scrum and go to good workplace practices, regardless of the process or methods you are using.

Finding relevant documentation that was lost due to turnover is good. I think that spending some time to look for documentation and assessing its current relevance is likely to be a good use of time, depending on how much time is spent. However, not sharing that information with the rest of the team is, in my opinion, extremely unprofessional. Communication and collaboration are essential elements of a team, and not sharing the documentation demonstrates that you aren't a team player.

Helping others on the team "level up" is definitely a good thing. Spending out of pocket money on someone else depends on the relationship and how its presented - if presented wrong, it could come off as condescending, but presented right it could be a great gesture. Teaching others how to effectively use their tools and working with them to help you improve the quality of your job is also good. However, it does seem like there are broader cultural issues between developers and testers in your organization, but that's a whole different set of issues that's beyond scope here.

Collaborating with the business analyst to understand exactly what needs to happen is a good thing. Particularly in the context of Scrum, this is called Product Backlog Refinement and the whole team should be doing this in some form or another (Scrum doesn't say how it happens, just that it does). However, "wiggling out" of repetitive stuff isn't so good. If the work needs to happen, it needs to happen and if it's a priority, then it's a priority and needs to happen sooner. I'm especially looking at unit testing - good, high quality automated test coverage (in the form of unit tests as well as at other levels of testing) is going to improve the quality of the system, provide living documentation as to what the system does, and raise flags or find issues sooner rather than later in the process.

If I had to review your performance - it would definitely be a mixed bag at this point. In the end, though, it would probably be a pretty mediocre review. Even if you are stellar in technical contributions, there's a lot lacking in teamwork, collaboration, and communication that would need serious improvement.

As far as recognition goes, that's beyond the scope of Scrum. It's organizational dependent. Some organizations do reward stellar individual contributions that have had an impact, while others don't. I have generally mixed feelings on the subject, and have seen some bad implementations of individual recognition programs, but I've also seen some good ones.

I will also say that if you were hired to put in a certain number of hours of work on the project and you improved your personal efficiency, I would expect you to fill the time with additional project work. Anything else would be extremely unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

Scrum or no-scrum - I think the question you have is more about the recognition that comes from helping others vs. the value of leaving the bar low so it's easy to exceed expectations with very little effort.

And I think my counter question is - what do you want for yourself?  An opportunity to work in an excellent team, where people learn together and help each other?  Or a team where people hoard knowledge and don't challenge each other much, and the only real joy is the joy of watching others scramble around in the dark?  If your whole team can work as efficiently as you do, doesn't that mean that the team as a whole will achieve a significantly larger number of story points (or whatever metric you use to rate scope size)?

And - bottom line - more story points means more/better feature which means a better product, which should mean a better chance of corporate success - resulting in better salaries, bonuses, stock options, etc. for all.

**TLDR - the bottom line is not whether you do better than your coworkers or have a better work/life balance - but that your whole company meets it's business goals better/more efficiently than it's competition.  Being the 1 awesome developer is not as conducive to this goal as being 1 of 10 awesome developers.**

---

**Appendix:**

My equivocal nature makes me feel forced to point out the down side of the rosy view of things.  In a perfect world, we'd all help each other, because collaboration is almost always the best outcome when everyone plays along.  The problem is - everyone doesn't always play along.  So the one time I would go against my advice above is if I had an office where I didn't think it would be a net win for me.  This is what I would call a "toxic team" and, personally, I'd strive to get away from a team like this ASAP, as my definition of personal growth is to work with people who challenge and support me - and a toxic team can't do either of these things.

Indications that you may have a toxic team:

- It's hard to get anyone to help anyone else - stuff like peer reviews, working as sounding boards for each other, or pitching in when some one is having trouble with a ticket doesn't happen.
- Unclear reasons for recognition - the times that people get recognition don't line up with a metric that makes any sense.  Particularly the more senior cases, someone should be capable enough and high-impact enough that the reasons for a public reward or recognition are easy to understand.
- Highly ranked engineers are NOT role models - either you can't trust them technically, or their teaching/mentoring skills are terrible.
- Managers don't seem to care who's helping who, who needs more help than others, or who's getting what done.

Another aspect is the assertion that technical success has some correlation to business success and that business success would be passed along to those who made the technical success happen.  That is true (as an example) of many high-tech companies, when they realize that their core value is coming from the software they produce relies on the software developers that produce that software.  ... but then there are many companies for whom the products of software development is a tangent and/or a necessary evil, so that the business folks don't see it as such a vital part of the equation.  Theoretically - if you had a good manager & engineering culture - you'd still get ahead in your career from helping others - but the payoff may not be *quite* as great as if the company realizes your team's value.

---

Footnote:

When I interview people for positions, I note how the engineer speaks about their team and their work - if my sense is that the engineer strove for self improvement but not team improvement, I usually rate them somewhere around mid level (depending on their skills).  If my perception is that the person was able to improve not only themselves but people around them and the processes they use - I rate them several grade levels higher than that.  .... so even if your current company is dumb and dysfunctional, the company hiring you for your next job may see things differently.  "I figured out this way to be really fast" is good... but "I helped the entire time do this thing really fast" - is better.

Answer (score -3):

What your organization is like answers this.

I'm currently on a relatively small team in a company where the tech department isn't large. I’m one level below the top guy and he just moved into the job, so if I want a promotion, I must leave.

One of the occurrences of that is that the long term stability of the software I'm writing is now irrelevant. I won’t be here in 2 years as I want a promotion, so the code only needs to pass QA and survive that long. I am more focused on adding features and dollar value figures to my resume. Forget about edge cases.

Same with small acts of leadership. There’s a small math error in one of our calculation functions. Costs $1500 a month. I have bigger numbers on my resume so I just leave it.

Reveal one of these to the general group, perhaps the Selenium one as it is already known. If they reward it, great, you know that there is a potential reason to continue. If you basically just get “cool”, don’t bother tell them anything.

I personally would never reveal the documentation unless I were team lead. That’s a cheat code that doesn’t degrade my skills and I can just say “oh, I assumed you knew” if found out. Never give up something that allows you to effortlessly stand above co-workers. That’s the ace in your pocket if you need time to care for a family member or want to do a Masters degree while working. Giving that up is not worth the 30 second pat on the back.